# How to get next token from string?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I want to write a small algorithm.

I'm facing the following issue: I have a `String` that can contain digits and the following symbols: `-`, `(`, `)`. I want to parse it, so I can get each symbol and number.

The method I want to write, (`getNextToken`) should return the symbols and numbers succesively. For example: `getNextToken("(123-456)-12-1")` should return:

- on the first call: `"("`
- on the second call: `"123"`
- on the third call: `"-"`

and so on.

The problem I'm facing is that each numeric part can contain several digits.

I understand that it's not a big deal to write this kind of function, but it is not a "primitive" function. So, does Java have an utilit class to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. An example might help.

Comment: @Mukul Goe added example to topic

Comment: I think that a regEx can solve your search problem. Maybe share your code ?

Comment: @RC. sorry for bad English. I call 1, 2, 3 as numbers and 123 is digit for me.

Comment: you can create your own method for parsing digits pretty easily using char array.

Comment: It's all splitted by `-` and `(` and `)`?, I mean, no more chars than it? Can you add some more examples? How many `(` and `)` can be on a single String? Are they always paired?

Comment: "Does Java contain a util class for this?"  No.  Java should, but `StringTokenizer` is pretty poorly written and won't work.  You should try this yourself though, it's not hard.  Start with finding characters in a string and deciding what to do with them.

Comment: @Frakcool it is valid mathematical expression

Comment: @gstackoverflow If it's a valid mathematical (or maybe arithmetical) expression, then: are the delimiters `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(` and `)`? Or are you only using `(`, `)` and `-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another regular expressions solution with the same output as [JohnTeixeira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33834886/1898236):

```
String input = "(123-456)-12-1";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([()-]|\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

And it does not use the "not recommended" `StringTokenizer` class. You can find the exact details of this regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/gG0yH3/1).

Answer (score 5):

java.util.StringTokenizer can be called to include the delimiters in the tokens

```
String str = "(123-456)-12-1";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( str,"-()",true);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
 }
```

returns

```
(
123    
-
456
)
-
12
-
1
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This is OK, but will yeild some unexpected results.  For example, what happens if you add some spaces to the original input string?

Comment: If you want to use spit it can be done with `String[] result = str.split("((?<=-)|(?=-))|((?<=\\))|(?=\\)))|((?<=\\()|(?=\\())");` which is way less readable to me but may have a longer life is they deprecate the tokenizer.

Comment: Yeah, right.  Which is more maintainable, the OP or that regex horror you just posted?  Sweet baby jebus people.  http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: @markspace True, if that is in the scope of the problem.  I am assuming that each token would be checked for validity.  If we used `String str = "(123-45 6)-12-1";` we would get `(` ... `45 6` ...  `1`.  If desired, the `45 6` could be stripped of white space or, if the scope calls for a stricter action, invalid tokens would throw an exception.

Comment: @JohnTeixeira Whitespace is so common in parsing that I assume it must be in the problem scope.  I guess it might not be, but that would be pretty unusual.

Comment: @markspace I agree that it comes up often.  Especially  if you are parsing something that was not meant to be parsed. e.g. natural language or human-readable logs.  I think it is less of an issue with things that are designed to be parsable like computer languages or CSV.  But with those you gain the issue of escaped characters.  In conclusion, there is always a gotcha in parsing :-)

Comment: @JohnTeixerira There is also another way that does not use `String.split` and uses a regex with only 12 characters, see my answer.

Comment: @mezzodrinker I like your RegEx better than mine.  I still am partial to the cleanness of the Tokenizer but if one feels unsure of its longevity I'd choose yours for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, and it's not really readable. That's the problem with regular expressions :\

```
String str = "(123-456)-12-1";
String splittedStr = Arrays.toString(str.split("((?<=-)|(?=-)|(?<=[(])|(?=[(])|(?<=[)])|(?=[)]))"));
System.out.println(splittedStr);
// Outputs: [(, 123, -, 456, ), -, 12, -, 1]
```

**Edit:**
I found that the regular expression that I used can be simplified a lot. This new example uses the new shortened version:

```
String str = "(123-456)-12-1";
String splittedStr = Arrays.toString(str.split("((?<=-|[(]|[)])|(?=-|[(]|[)]))"));
System.out.println(splittedStr);
// Output: [(, 123, -, 456, ), -, 12, -, 1]
```

Comment: I think this explains some issues with that regular expression you used: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/